# Excel function: How to convert text data into numbers?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a paragraph of words that I want to filter and rank them in numbers accordingly. For instance, in one cell I have this:

"Apple; banana; orange; pineapple; watermelon". And in return, I want to rank them in order "5, 4, 3, 2, 1" in a column respectively (Apple being 5 and banana being 4 and so on.). My text data can be the fruits in another order too.

The function I require is similar to vlookup, but just that now instead of a table array, I have a chunk of text in just one cell.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this [interesting solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803560/excel-formula-to-extract-a-string-of-text-delimited-by-markers-from-cells) and extract the data from the cell first, since the data is delimited. You could create the array on a temporary sheet.

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,";",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999))
```